# How to include d.ts files in angular library

Tags: angular

How can I include d.ts files in angular(16) library during build. I have the file inside my library folder but when I try to build the library but it fails because it cannot resolve the reference from "**.mjs".

Any ideas what changes I need to do inside my configuration files?

Thanks in advance